# How to convert reponse stream to blob on javascript client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, blob

I am unable to create a blob from the response stream of a request (the response comes from a node js server), here is the code:

```
fetch('/api/load', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
  body: src

}).then((response) => {
  const reader = response.body.getReader()

  return new ReadableStream({
    start(controller) {
      return pump()

      function pump() {
        return reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
          if (done) {
            controller.close();
            return;
          }
          controller.enqueue(value);
          return pump();
        })
      }
    }
  })

}).then((stream) => {
  // What to do next with the stream???
})
```

I already tried `new Blob([new Uint8Array(stream)], {type: 'image/jpeg'})`, but it doesn't work :(

**What is the correct way to create a blob from the stream?**

Comment: What prevents you to simply do `then((response) => response.ok && response.blob())`?

Comment: it prevents me beacuase response.blob() doesn't work, in my case the response content type is 'application/octet-stream'

Comment: So what? Jist create a new Blob from that using the correct type, or response.arrayBuffer().then(buf=>new Blob([buf])).